# Closing WPF ContextMenu when executing one of its MenuItem commands

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to write a simple WPf application. The application has a few controls and one of them - a context menu. The menu is used to save/load files. The load file menu item command opens a standard Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog. The problem is that the context menu remains as it was (as its blocked by the command execution I believe) and it's over the pop-up.

I tried to use a normal thread, invoke the open file dialog via

```
contextMenu.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Background, new Action(() => { ... }));
```

and via the named aync method, but they all keep the context menu living on the screen.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: you can set the visibility of the context menu to hidden after executing your command

Comment: Did you try setting the StaysOpen property to false?

Comment: I did try setting the property and it did nothing. The problem  is the context menu closes **after** command execution. It remains open when the `OpenFileDialog` is open (so when the program "hangs" inside the command handler) which is not ideal as it is on top of the dialog.

Comment: I created a TextBox with a ContextMenu that has one item that opens the OpenFileDialog and I do not get the behavior you describe. Can you post your ContextMenu XAML and the full code of the Command it executes?

Comment: I would rather not post the code as it's for private usage only. May I ask if you use Windows 7 or 8? I found out a few days ago a difference in context menu item icon displaying - the icons on Windows 7 use defined dimension sizes while on Windows 8 they are cut to 16x16.